# Is there any support for D3.js in SpagoBI ?

Tags: d3.js

I want to integrate my D3.js charts into SpagoBI. Is there any support for D3.js charts in SpagoBI like it has support for Highcharts and JFree Charts which are also java-script libraries.

Comment: A search of their website/documentation would suggest that this is not the case.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this? I mean using SpagoBI SDK